# Determining if a .NET type is dynamic (created using Reflection.Emit)

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5

While the .NET 4 framework provides the `Assembly.IsDynamic` method, that's not the case with .NET 2.0/3.5.

The use case is simple: for logging purposes, I want to determine the underlying type name of an entity that might be wrapped by a dynamic proxy **without** having any references to NHibernate or Castle (which know about the proxy)

For example, I might have a `CatProxYadaYada`, but I'm interested in `Cat`.

What's the easiest way to get that type? I was thinking of this skeleton:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
while (IsProxy_Dynamic_Whatever(obj))
  type = type.BaseType;
return type;
```

Comment: This breaks the abstraction provided by proxies - the main idea of which is that the consumer isn't supposed to know/care about the difference.  What kind of logging are you doing that requires you to know this?

Comment: @Aaronaught, I just want to log stuff like "Cat #324 failed validation" passing the method an object that inherits from my Entity class. That is, the code doesn't even know that the instance is a (proxy of) Cat. What I'm interested in, actually, is not the type, but the type *name*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the assembly was generated using `Emit`, then you *should* be able to verify this by checking if the type's assembly is an `AssemblyBuilder`.  In other words, something like this:

```
static Type GetNonEmittedType(Type t)
{
    if (t.Assembly is AssemblyBuilder)
        return GetNonEmittedType(t.BaseType);
    return t;
}
```

This might not work for every kind of dynamic proxy - it really depends on how it was generated.  But it works with `Emit`.